# Cookie is not set at the POSTMAN

Tags: api, go, postman

Am trying to set a cookie at the POSTMAN by writing the code blow using Golang

```
sub := handlers.NewSunscribers(s)
router := mux.NewRouter()  
router.HandleFunc("/sub/set", sub.SetCookie).Methods("POST")
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router))

type SubHandlers struct {
sub storage.Sub
}



func (s SubHandlers) SetCookie(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("Am trying to set a cookie")
  cookie := &http.Cookie{
    Name:   "name",
    Value:  "Biola",
    MaxAge: 3000,
}

w.Write([]byte("Cookie set Successfully"))
http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
```

}

So after i ran this program and i checked the POSTMAN "cookie" botton below the "send"
botton and i realised that the cookie is not there.
Pls can anybody explain where am doing things wrong?.

Comment: You cannot set a cookie after you have already written the response body (cookies are sent in the header).

Answer (score 1):

set cookie first, then write a response. Example:

```
http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
w.Write([]byte("Cookie set Successfully"))
```

Comment: ,thanks but the cookie still not set at the POSTMAN cookie

Comment: `json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("Am trying to set a cookie")` should be also after `SetCookie`

Answer (score 0):

I later realized that you can not set cookie if write to the response
body first, cookie must be set first then  other messages to the
response bodycan be follow:

```
func setCookie(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    cookie := &http.Cookie{
        Name:   "name",
        Value:  "Bola",
        MaxAge: 300,
    }
    http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
    w.Write([]byte("Cookie set Successfully"))
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).